# firstborn status after the arrival of the moshiach

Tags: kohen-priest, bechor-firstborn, temple-service-avoda, masechet-taanis, latid-lavo-future

The Ohr Hachaim (Bamidbar 3,45) says a chiddush that seems to not have any obvious source, that לעתיד לבא (after the arrival of mashiach) the Avoda in the Beis Hamikdash will return to the firstborn! (we know that they did have this role till the חטא העגל).

I have seen many good questions on this chiddush, but the following one stood out. The Gemara Tannis 17a states (according to the חכמים) that a Kohen בזמן הזה (nowadays) may not drink wine because perhaps the Beis Hamikdash will be rebuilt then and he will be called to return to service in the Beis Hamikdash, and one cannot perform the Avodah in an inebriated state.

The question is if the Avoda will be done by the firstborn (בכורים) also, then why don't they have the same prohibition like the Kohanim not dring intoxicated beverages?

Perhaps one can say that only the firstborn of that generation (of moshiach) will merit to do the Avoda, but the Bechorim of today lost their Kedusha by their "Pidyon" Haben... What are your thoughts?

Comment: Relevant: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30135/27180

Answer (score 1):

Great question! It is worthy to note that the source for the Or Hachaim is the Yalkut 364, but when one looks for this Yalkut its not there!?

@user2709 here: [Source for bechorot losing/reclaiming priesthood](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28295/source-for-bechorot-losing-reclaiming-priesthood) brought words from the Rebbe which I think might answer your question.

This is what he says:

דלפי״ז לכאורה מובן שכבר בימות המשיח לפני תחיית המתים יתבטל לגמרי חטא העגל ותוחזר אז העבודה לבכורות כיון שיהי׳ כבר אז כמו שהי׳ לפני חטא הדעת. ובס׳ ׳מועדים וזמנים׳ (ה״ז סי׳ קסט) הביא דברי האור החיים הנ״ל והקשה ע״ז דדבריו צ״ב האיך ישתנו דיני התורה בביאת המשיח שבכורות מזרע ישראל שהם זרים יוכשרו לעבודה, וכן הקשה ממ״ש הרמב״ם בסוף הל׳ מלכים שמלך המשיה מייהם שבט לוי לכהונה משמע ששבט לוי יעבדו העבודה עיי״ש,

"That even in moshiach's times the avoda will go back to the bechoros (before tchiyas hamaisim) when the punishment of the golden calf will be finished. He brings that R Sternbuch asks that the rambam says the leviim will be working in the bais hamikdosh. He goes on to answer it saying they both will be doing the avoda. I would suggest a simple answer. He doesnt say the avaira of the egel will be forgiven straight away only it will happen in moshiach's times before tchiyas hameisim. **That may take some time and until then we will need the leviim.** His other question how can someone from the other tribes classified as a 'zor' be kosher. The b'chorim then will not be classified as such."

I think since he mentions that it will take some time until the bechors assume position as Kohanim, therefore the rule of not drinking intoxicating drinks wont apply anymore, it will only apply when the bechors get reinstated as Kohanim when Mashiach comes.

Comment: Yalkut: https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Torah.364.1?vhe=Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Torah&lang=bi

Comment: Ahh, thanks, didn't see that

Comment: thanks! especially if you hold like the Yerushalmi that the rebuild of the Temple will come before the coming of the Mashiach, see here https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Maaser_Sheni.5.2.9?lang=bi

Comment: Yes! That is a good point as well